# openssl_sign with OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1 algorithm in golang

Tags: php, go, openssl

I have some php code like this

```
        $signature = '';
        $data = strval($aMessage);
        if (!openssl_sign($data, $signature, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)) {
            return null;
        }
        $signature = base64_encode($signature);
```

I make a plan to move it into golang. so I have the code like this

```
    var rpk *rsa.PrivateKey
    var bs []byte
    if rpk, err = c.getRSAPrivateKey(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if bs, err = json.Marshal(c); err != nil {
        return
    }
    var hash = crypto.SHA1.New()
    hash.Write(bs)

    if bs, err = rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, rpk, crypto.SHA1, hash.Sum(nil)); err != nil {
        return
    }
    return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(bs), err
```

when bs have a small length it works well and the result is the same as php code, but it works bad
when bs has a big length. where is my wrong?

I hope the result is always the same

Updated:
the problem is. golang base64encoding , I hav solved with below codes

```
    var b64s = base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(bs)
    b64s = strings.ReplaceAll(b64s, "-", "+")
    b64s = strings.ReplaceAll(b64s, "_", "/")
```

Comment: What is the type of `c` in Golang code?

Comment: c is a struct which can be json Marshal to a json string . and it is equal to $aMessage in php code

Comment: the problem is golang base64encoding finally I have solved it with the topic update contents

Comment: Good to know. You can add it as an answer with some additional info and mark it as a correct answer, so that it can be useful to someone else.